# How can I have Devel generate nodes with different terms and not always the same term?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I am using the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module to generate content (nodes) as a test. The content type has a field referencing a vocabulary that has terms already added to it. When 1000 nodes are generated, Devel assigns the same term to every node (the first term in the vocabulary). Is it possible to have Devel assign different terms at random to different nodes? How about setting one term as the default value for the field?

Comment: Can you try creating some vocabulary terms through devel generate and then try generating the nodes again.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when you have a default term chosen for the content type.

If you remove the default, it will then randomly choose terms that already exist (if they exist) or randomly generate terms if the vocabulary allows it.